# Trying to plot a parametric curve using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

 \begin{axis}[
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis equal, axis x line=middle, axis y line=
     middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-4,ymax=4] 

 \addplot [domain=-2:2, samples=590, red,very thick]({(3*x)/(1+x^3)},{(3*x^2)/(1+x^3)}); 

\end{axis} 

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

See above my code for the Folium of Descartes. My question is, how do I make it look like the folium. I tried to increase the samples, but after I  put 600, I get an error (dimension too large)

Comment: You are using slope to parametrize the curve. This is not ideal and in particular, the curve abruptly stops at slope = ±2. Would you care to switch to using polar coordinate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stick to slope, you have to be careful with domains.

[image: Descartes folimu]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis equal, axis x line=middle, axis y line=
     middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-4,ymax=4] 

 \addplot [domain=-1:180, smooth,samples=2000, red,very thick]({(3*x)/(1+x^3)},{(3*x^2)/(1+x^3)}); 

 \addplot [domain=-180:-1, smooth,samples=2000, red,very thick]({(3*x)/(1+x^3)},{(3*x^2)/(1+x^3)}); 

\end{axis} 


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It would be better to plot it in polar coordinates.